# Wordpress Comment status changing hook

Tags: php, filter, wordpress

Is there anybody who knows a hook or a filter that might help by triggering a function when the administrator aprooves a comment? I've made a lot of researches, but nothiing comes out.

I am working on a plugin snd something like that will become crucial. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the hook `comment_{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}`

It's in file /wp-includes/comment.php (http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/tags/3.2/wp-includes/comment.php)

Search for the line

```
do_action("comment_{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}", $comment);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank's